# About the initialization of the UIView

Tags: uiview, ios4

Support there are 2 views in the XIB file: UIView1, UIView2.

And the UIView1Owner is the owner of the UIView1. I guess when the XIB is loaded, it will automatically load the 2 views. However, the constructor (initWithFrame:) in the UIView1Owner will not be triggered.

It seems there is some magic behind the scene, and I am wondering how to add some stuff to the constructor of the UIView.

Comment: Is `UIView1Owner` a UIViewController?

Comment: An answer requires your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the "initWithFrame:" section of http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

> > If you use interface builder to design your interface, this method is not called when your view objects are subsequently loaded from the nib file. Objects in the nib are reconstituted and initialized using their initWithCoder: method...

Place any code you want in the initWithCoder: method.

Answer (score 0):

initWithFrame will be called only for two created from xib objects (UIView1, UIView2). xib owner is assumed to exist before xib load.